# observable() does not update selects selected item as expected

Tags: knockout.js

The Html:

```
<select id="Catagories_CategoryId" data-bind="options: CategoryServiceTypes, 
    optionsText: 'Name',                        
    optionsCaption: 'Please select a Category...',                                        
    value: SelectedCategoryType">
</select>
```

In the code sample below I've just deleted an item in a grid, so I repopulate the grid via `LoadServiceTypesFromSvc()`

```
obj.SelectedCategoryTypeHolder(obj.SelectedCategoryType()); //copy the old selected object
pager.LoadServiceTypesFromSvc(); //repop
ko.utils.arrayForEach(obj.CategoryServiceTypes(), function(data) {                                                        
    if (data.CategoryId() == obj.SelectedCategoryTypeHolder().CategoryId()) {
        obj.SelectedCategoryType(data);
        alert('selected ' + obj.SelectedCategoryType().Name()); //shows the name of the item I'm aiming for
    }
});
```

`LoadServiceTypesFromSvc()` also repopulated the select. I want to set the selects selected value to what it was before the data refresh.

Even though the alert confirms that obj.SelectedCategoryType() has been set to what I want it set to - the select itself remains unchanged and still shows the default 'Please Select...' first item.

What am I missing?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have asynchronous AJAX-request in your `.LoadServiceTypesFromSvc()`?

Comment: no, it's synchronous edit: actually i need to check that... good point!

Comment: it's async ($.ajax()) but it all happens in request.done()

Comment: The block `ko.utils.arrayForEach(...)` must run inside `request.done(...)` too.

Comment: @f_martinez - yep - I needed to run the loop in the request.done() of LoadServiceTypesFromSvc() not the request.done() of the delete function. Awesome. Make your solution the answer and I'll tick it. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run ko.utils.arrayForEach(...) block against every item returned by LoadServiceTypesFromSvc() in the .done function